# MySQL JOIN on three tables, including a WHERE?

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables structured like this:

```
usergroups:
id
title

field:
id
title

field_permissions:
id
field_id
group_id
```

The purpose of these tables is to have multiple groups assigned to a field (so that more than one group of people in the application can access it).  Usergroups are given permission to access a particular field via the field_permissions table.

What I need to do (using mysql) is get a list of all the usergroups and a column indicating if they have permission to access a field (NULL, otherwise). (I hope that makes sense).  here is an example of what I have done so far.

Using this query:

```
SELECT usergroups.id AS group_id, usergroups.title AS usergroup, field_permissions.id AS permission_id
FROM usergroups
LEFT JOIN field_permissions ON field_permissions.group_id=usergroups.id
LEFT JOIN field ON field.id=field_permissions.field_id
WHERE field.id=1
```

I get the following result:

```
group_id   usergroup      permission_id
=======================================
1          Super User     10
2          Basic User     11
3          Administrator  12
```

That gives me the usergroups which DO have permissions on that particular field (the field in question having an id of 1).  I know they have permission to that field simply because a permission id which relates the two exists.

What I am looking for is this:

```
group_id   usergroup      permission
====================================
1          Super User     10
2          Basic User     11
3          Administrator  12
4          Public User    NULL
```

To show that group_id 4 does NOT have permission for this field.

Currently I am achieving this result in PHP by getting all the usergroups that exist and then looking for each one in relation to the field in the field_permissions table using a foreach loop.  But that is a tedious loop and I am sure it could be optimized to have only a single query to give me that information.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The `left outer join` keeps all rows from the first table.  When there is no match, it produces a `NULL` value.  Your `where` is undoing the outer join.  You can fix this by moving the condition into the `on` clause:

```
SELECT usergroups.id AS group_id, usergroups.title AS usergroup,
       field_permissions.id AS permission_id
FROM usergroups LEFT JOIN
     field_permissions
     ON field_permissions.group_id = usergroups.id LEFT JOIN
     field
     ON field.id = field_permissions.field_id AND
        field.id = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this definitely work.

```
SELECT fp.id as field_permissions_id,f.id AS field_id,f.title,ug.id AS usergroup_id,ug.title FROM field_permissions AS fp LEFT JOIN field AS f ON fp.field_id = f.id LEFT JOIN usergroups AS ug ON fp.group_id = ug.id WHERE fp.field_id = f.id AND fp.group_id = ug.id
```

Answer (score 0):

To get expected result you should use `field_permissions` in `WHERE`, not `field`.

The reason is, that if `field` is NULL, this recond won't get into result.

Also you might want to add another condition to where:

```
WHERE field.id = 1 OR field.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks gordon, you answer didn't work perfectly first shot, but it was a good start! 
Using your answer exactly as it was delivered all 121 field_permissions rows in the table with their assigned usergroups, which wasn't quite what I needed ( I have tried this before).
This, however, worked:

```
SELECT usergroups.id AS group_id, usergroups.title AS usergroup,
       field_permissions.id AS permission_id
FROM usergroups 
LEFT JOIN field_permissions ON field_permissions.group_id = usergroups.id AND field_permissions.field_id=3 
LEFT JOIN field ON field.id = field_permissions.field_id AND field.id = 3;
```

That gave me this:

```
group_id   usergroup      permission
====================================
1          Super User     10
2          Basic User     11
3          Administrator  12
4          Public User    NULL
```

Notice how I added your AND statement to the last LEFT JOIN and another one to the first LEFT JOIN.

Hope this is useful to someone in future!